# spTransform cutting off part of ROI in stereographic projection

Tags: r, sp

I'd like to have a map of land above 50N in the stereographic projection.  I use the following code but as you can see, some land is cut out.

```
  proj<- "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=71 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84
    +towgs84=0,0,0" 


    data("wrld_simpl", package = "maptools")                                                                            
    wm <- crop(wrld_simpl, extent(-180, 180, 50, 90)) 
    wm <- spTransform(wm, CRSobj = CRS(proj))  

    ### plot land
    plot(wm, col="grey", border="grey")

#add wrapper circle
pts=SpatialPoints(rbind(c(-180,50),c(0,50),c(180,80),c(180,80)), crs(data))
my_line = SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(seq(-180,180,0.5),rep(50,721))), ID="outer")), CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
my_line1<-st_as_sf(my_line)
bounds<-st_transform(my_line1,crs =proj)
plot(bounds,col="gray42",add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that the crop line is a straight line in lat-long with few vertices. `spTransform` only transforms vertices, so a straight line between two points in lat-long becomes a straight-line in projected coordinates, which is what you see.

To fix, you need to densify straight lines with few vertices into lines with more vertices, and you can use the `smoothr` package function `densify` which does a pretty good job here. Install with `install.packages("smoothr")` as usual and `library(smoothr)` to get it.

```
> wm <- crop(wrld_simpl, extent(-180, 180, 50, 90)) 
> plot(spTransform(densify(wm),proj))
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thank you, @Spacedman!